# Compare items in an Array to items in a Variant in VB6

Tags: arrays, vba, vb6, variant

I have a Variant in VB6 with thousands of Strings.

I also have an array of fixed length.

I need to compare the contents of each and add the ones that match to a list.

```
if array(i) = variant(1,i) then
'add to list
End if
```

I cannot figure out how to iterate over both properly in order to compare, as the method I use to iterate over the Variant() stops after going through each item. So it never checks to see if it any item is equal to i+1 in the array.

```
Private Sub dp_Click()
    Dim fArray
    fArray = Array("a", "b", "c")

    LstAPens.ListItems.Clear
    LstUPens.ListItems.Clear

    For x = 0 To UBound(fArray)
        Dim i As Long,  m As Integer

        'Do Until batcharray(0, i) = "End"
        '   tmpArray(i) = UCase(batcharray(1, i))
        'Loop

        Do Until batcharray(0, i) = "End"
            If (InStr(1, UCase(batcharray(1, i)), UCase(fArray(x))) > 0) Then
                LstAPens.ListItems.Add
                    With LstAPens.ListItems(m + 1)
                     .SubItems(1) = batcharray(1, i) 'Tagname
                    End With
                    m = m + 1
            End If
            i=i+1
        Loop
    Next x
End Sub
```

I tried to convert the Variant to an array but it did not work.

The only item that is found is the first one in the array, then the Variant is no longer iterated over as it reached the end.

How can I iterate over the Variant called batchArray in this example, and compare it to the contents of an array?

Comment: Your iteration variable i is never assigned nor incremented in that loop...was that just omitted?

Comment: Apologies, I hand typed out the code as I am working on an isolated server. It is in code I am working on. I will edit question.

Comment: Continuing to review this, I don't see how the `until` loop code either *ever* executes or ever *stops* executing as posted given that loop variable i never changes. Wondering if something is omitted? Appreciate if you could review/verify the posted code..Thx!! :)

Comment: Hmmm...I'd probably at least try moving the declaration of 'i' outside the loop, and explicitly setting it to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really isn't a `Variant` problem, it's just a looping/control variable issue.

Even though you have your DIM statement inside your main loop, VB does not treat that as a "redeclaration" and reset/reinitialize its value before your UNTIL loop. As a result, 'i' will increment to 1 and then retain its value between iterations of your outer loop, thus remaining stuck on the single value in batchArray and the iteration ceases.

Move the declaration outside the loop, reset it to 0 before the `UNTIL` loop, and see if that solves your problem:

```
Dim i as Long

For x = 0 To UBound(fArray)
    Dim m As Integer
    i = 0
    Do Until batcharray(0, i) = "End"
        If (InStr(1, UCase(batcharray(1, i)), UCase(fArray(x))) > 0) Then
            LstAPens.ListItems.Add
                With LstAPens.ListItems(m + 1)
                 .SubItems(1) = batcharray(1, i) 'Tagname
                End With
                m = m + 1
        End If
        i=i+1
    Loop
Next x
```